# Extjs : Hidden content being initialized on start up

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am working on an Extjs existing application that is having performance issues.

Basically, app.js is launching a container class that extends Panel. This panel has 3 items which are separate components for tabs in the application (home, results, projections). Each component shows grids and graphs and lots of ajax calls are made to get the data.

The problem is that all the ajax calls for results and projections are being made when the application starts up. I expected just the home component to initialize as it's the only visible component on start up. There is no point initializing results and projections until those tabs are clicked.

Below are the layouts the components extend :

Home extends Container

Results extends Container

Projections extends Panel

deferredRender defaults to True as per the docs so i expected the hidden components not to be initialized until they are visible. Is there something i am missing regarding how deferredRender works ? Are there any application settings that could affect how this functions ?

Answer (score 2):

set the property [autoload](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.data.ProxyStore.html#cfg-autoLoad) of all your stores to false:

```
store: {
    autoLoad : false,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried adding to the Stores and TreeStores but not seeing any reduction in calls. Could a local build setting be affecting this ?

Comment: @grimmus Check stores for `remoteSort: true` config. Not sure about ExtJS 5, but in ExtJS 4 this setting cause store to auto load data regardless of `autoLoad: false` setting.